# Is there a rasa story log

Tags: chatbot, rasa

in rasa

my chatbot is not following the story well.  Is there a way to collect data about a conversation and see why it chose the story step it chose?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--debug` flag to any CLI command (e.g., `rasa shell`, `rasa run`) to get the logs which are going to show you how the intent of the user message is classified as well as the actions predicted by the policies. I would also recommend [writing test stories](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/testing-your-assistant#writing-test-stories) and checking if you get any failures.

Comment: Thank you, that points me in the right direction.

I did try writing test stories and generated confusion matrixes.  It looks from the surface that the matrices indicate that my intents are all ok but the stories are confused.

I will research --debug and see what that can do for me.